# RoR SASS loading not working in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What would cause this to be the case? I cannot find any relevant information in pretty extensive searching. It works fine in development, but in production it's totally ignored. My personal custom CSS files are working but gem based ones like bootstrap-sass that I load with application.css.scss through import's does NOT work in production mode. I do not see any errors either.

Comment: Just tested again in development. works fine there.